# Performance Counter are always zero in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

> By using Following Code i am trying to retrieve the CPU Usages, but its always return 0, i am also using timer in code so that the following  function calling every 5 sec,
>
> But the strange thing is that ,if i use the PerformanceCounter control then  code its work perfectly ,but if i use PerformanceCounter class the its not working.

```
Private Function GetAllCpuUsages()
    Dim cpucounter As New PerformanceCounter
    cpucounter.CategoryName = "Processor"
    cpucounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time"
    cpucounter.InstanceLifetime = PerformanceCounterInstanceLifetime.Global
    cpucounter.InstanceName = "_Total"
    cpucounter.MachineName = "."
    cpucounter.ReadOnly = True
    TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToInt32(cpucounter.NextValue).ToString()
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are doing it wrong.  You create a *new* counter every time you call the method.  Its first reported value will always be zero since it doesn't have any history yet of the previous time interval.  Instead, you need to create the counter just once.  Best done in the form constructor:

```
Dim cpucounter As New PerformanceCounter

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    cpucounter.CategoryName = "Processor"
    cpucounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time"
    cpucounter.InstanceName = "_Total"
    Timer1.Interval = 1000
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Label1.Text = Convert.ToInt32(cpucounter.NextValue).ToString()
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd prefer to add the first call of NextValue() into Sub New to get zero value just there. Why not?